# Android - Setting two repeating alarms not working

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am using the following piece of code for setting 2 alarms in Android that repeat everyday.

```
 //I check if the reminder is already set or not..
    boolean b = prefs.getBoolean(CommonLib.SharedPrefsKeys.ATTENDANCE_COUNTER_ON, false);
    if (!b) {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AttendanceReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(CommonLib.SharedPrefsKeys.ATTENDANCE_COUNTER_ON, true).apply();    
    }
```

Now here is the code for my second alarm..

```
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

I have added the receiver in my manifest.xml file too.

```
  <receiver android:name="com.channeli.bunkometer.material.utils.AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />
  <receiver android:name="com.channeli.bunkometer.material.utils.AttendanceReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

I have 2 receiver classes that have onReceive function, but my alarms are not working always. Am I missing something?

**Note**: I have given different IDs in getBroadcast method (0 in 1st alarm, and 1 in 2nd alarm) so that they do not overwrite each other. Still I am not able to find the mistake. What is it that I am missing out?

Comment: post you `menifest.xml` file.

Comment: @Kaushal28 I have posted the xml code. I have attached the receivers in my xml. Problem is sometimes the alarms work sometimes they don't.